# MariaDB: Executing stored procedure, Select denied, privilege via role

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb, role

I have created a stored procedure with a user *db_owner* (Definer = *db_owner*, SQL Security Definer). This procedure selects some data from a table. The *db_owner* has full select privilege on all tables of his database via a **role**. Executing the procedure works fine, also selects from this table.
Another user *db_connect* has execute privilege for the procedure, executing procedure works also fine, but I get an error "ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user **db_owner'**@'host' for table 'xxx'"

If I grant a privilege to the **user** *db_owner* (grant select on db.'xxx' to db_owner@'host') without using the role, it works. Have anyone a better idea? I want to use roles.

MariaDB 10.3

Comment: One option may be to use the `ROLE` itself as the definer of the stored procedure: `DEFINER=<ROLE_of_db_owner>`.

Comment: Your solution works fine, thank you very much! Now the procedure runs under the privileges of the role.